# Is it normal for my grub to change color without me doing anything?

Tags: 17.04

It happens that the Ubuntu grub changed color without me doing anything. The original grub was purple but now it is blue, and also another thing is that the `sudo su` does not ask for a password, in doing so I start the mode root automatically without asking for a password.

Comment: Welcome to askubuntu! For the issue on sudo, please refer to this question even though it is already five years old: https://askubuntu.com/questions/153933/no-password-prompt-at-sudo-command If this doesn't change anything, please post your output of  `sudo visudo` here.