# login as root user with full privilages

Tags: login, root, privileges

I dont like to enter password for every software to install or other thing like it.i look for a way that can login with root user as default when ubuntu started.
in fact i want login with a user that have full permission .

Comment: I would not recommend this as it makes your system much less secure. But if you really want to see the duplicate question.

Answer (score 0):

you can type `sudo -s` onnce in terminal to have root access all the time you are logged in.
there is also `sudo -i`

to see the differences check this :
[sudo -i ,sudo -s](http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=983645&s=37773131be5c8a994c61f647853821dd&p=6188826#post6188826)

Comment: every time I log in I must enter that to terminal?

Comment: sure than you are root,...

Answer (score 0):

There are various reasons why you **would not** want to do this, referring to security issues etc... for example anybody that has access to your user account could install anything without being prompted for a password.

Anyway, it's your user account...

An answer was placed [here](https://askubuntu.com/questions/235084/how-do-i-remove-ubuntus-password-requirement), that I think answers your question.

Comment: thanks .I find to how do it.but because i am beginner i can not edit file with terminal . I enter the sudo visudo and open the file in terminal and make change in file.but I do not know how to save change in file.

Comment: if you open terminal `ctrl+alt+t` and type `cd ../` you will see a list of files and folders, typing in the name of a folder will direct you to that file. Typing in `../` will take you one file up (e.g. the parent folder). using this you can direct yourself to the file mentioned in the link. Once you are there you can use `sudo touch filename.fileformat`, type in your password, and then `sudo nano filename.fileformat`, which will open the file in terminal. Once here you can make your changes and press **the buttons:** `ctrl+x` and then `y` and then `return` to save and exit.