# How to give a quicklauncher or shortcut administration privilege?

Tags: launcher, sudo, command-line, shortcuts

I have a quicklauncher in a plasma widget (which is the same as a shortcut) which runs a command which needs administration privilege. I use the quicklauncher frequently and do not want to type root password each time.

Is there a way to give root privilege to the icon or  somehow add the password to the command which is run by the icon?

Comment: I think this is what you are looking for: http://askubuntu.com/questions/147241/execute-sudo-without-password

Comment: the question seems to be terminal **window** specific, the icon runs a command without any windows. btw, I'll try to check that threads options.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

if you would like to run it without a terminal window, and set the password in the command specifically (without editing sudoers), another option is to create a script like:

```
#!/bin/bash
echo <password> | sudo -S <command>
```

-and run it from your launcher (quicklauncher).

The command in the launcher would be:

`/bin/bash 'path_to_script.sh'`

The downside is that you have your password stored in a file on a risky location. To work around the safety issue, you could locate the scrypt on a small truecrypt volume.

(inpsired by [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18099824/run-sudo-command-with-password) thread)

Comment: still it's terminal window specific, because the icon itself launches a dialog box for the password. But I think it can be disabled by disabling feedback. I wonder if no terminal is opened it will work!

Comment: I am not that familiar with plasma, but a "regular" .desktopfile runs this script without a terminal window. I was thinking, you could work around the safety issue to locate the script on a tiny truecrypt volume on a stick or so.