# How can I run a program (wine) as a distinct user by shortcut?

Tags: 14.04, wine, shortcuts, playonlinux, accounts

I'm running Ubuntu 14.04 and I want to run wine under a different account for security reasons. I also want to access it from different accounts. So I made an account called wine and now I want a way to make it easy to run Wine or Playonlinux w/o having to run special commands each time. (I'm setting this up for my family who each have different accounts.)

Comment: You've got the record for the slowest acceptance of any of my answers now!  **:D** (Favour returned: answer upvoted!)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is a 4-step process:

1. Install `gksu` by `apt-get install gksu`
2. Create a bash script that uses `gksu - wine` to change to the user `wine` and then execute the commands needed.  (as that script is used by all users, it should probably go in `/usr/local/bin`.
    
   (***For the cautious types:*** try it in `~/bin` first)
3. Turn X11 forwarding on by adding the following line as last line: `export $(dbus-launch)` to your `/etc/bash.bashrc`
4. Create a link (or a desktop file) to that script and put it on the individual user's desktop.

**Pro Tip:** If you want to run that link without a password, [have a look here](https://askubuntu.com/questions/147241/execute-sudo-without-password)

Comment: `gksu` or `gksudo` might be better since OP probably wants to run GUI applications. `sudo` doesn't work so well for application starters. ;-]

Comment: You might want to mention that `gksu` is not installed by default; the script will not do anything noticeble then :)).

Comment: Danke @DavidFoerster!  I'm running with X11 forwarding, so I tend to forget... :(

Comment: Dank je @JacobVlijm.  Adapted!

Comment: I made this file [/usr/local/bin/playonlinux.sh] 
#!/bin/bash
gksu -u wine /usr/bin/playonlinux

It fails silently. What did I do wrong?

Comment: Turn X11 forwarding on: In your `/etc/bash.bashrc` add the following line as last line: `export $(dbus-launch)` and try again.

Comment: Is there any way to do the sudo without entering a password? @DavidFoerster