# Adduser and setting up files for each new user

Tags: shortcuts, adduser

Does Ubuntu have a directory where new users get the default folder contents? I'm trying to install a shortcut for all users to playonlinux, including users I've not added yet. Can that be done?

Comment: If you want to know what I'm doing this for check out http://askubuntu.com/questions/582182/how-can-i-run-a-program-wine-as-a-distinct-user-by-shortcut

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The contents of `/etc/skel` are copied to new users home.

There are 2 strategies to make system changes for all users:

1. Edit the appropriate global system files and remove the same settings from the user files. This is the way I prefer to make changes, and enforce them, so that they apply to all users.

For example, to change the bash prompt for all users, edit `/etc/bash.bashrc`

2. Add things to /etc/skel . This will put config files in a user home directory. Since these files are placed in $HOME, users may modify them.