# Pass sudo command from GUI

Tags: command-line, sudo, gui

I have a shell script using some `sudo` command. When I run this script from terminal - it asks me for password and runs with any problem. But when I try to run executable shell script form GUI (double click) it does not ask me for password - so does not work.

Example of my shell script:

```
c1=$(dmidecode -t 4 | grep ID | sed 's/.*ID://;s/ //g' | sha1sum | awk '{print $1}')
```

How to run script from GUI and pass all `sudo` commands with no problem?

Comment: TL;DR: use `gksudo` or `pkexec`.

Comment: @JonasCz the dupe is about getting a GUI password prompt, not running GUI applications - if OP wants to avoid having a password prompt at all, they should ask that

Answer (score -1, accepted):

You can [pass the password to `sudo` from the standard input](https://superuser.com/questions/67765/sudo-with-password-in-one-command-line), like this:

```
echo 'yourpassword' | sudo -S yourcommand
```

Using `-S` tells `sudo` to read the password from stdin, which comes from the `echo 'yourpassword'` bit.

You could also [edit visudo, so that `sudo` will never prompt for the password](https://askubuntu.com/a/147265/383125), either only for your specific comand, or always.

***Warning: storing your password in plain text is an extremely bad idea***

Comment: Great it works well for me. Thank you so much.

Comment: **Storing admin passwords in PLAIN TEXT???** Are you mad?

Comment: Bad advice. Seriously. You -never- ever provide a password to the process list. This is asking for that system to get compromised. The 2 answers in the dupe linked should be used.