# Can I execute a program with a sudo command through a shortcut?

Tags: command-line, sudo

I've created a file containing these two lines of code:

```
#!/bin/sh 
sudo sh -c "sync; echo 3 > /proc/sys/vm/drop_caches"
```

I have ticked (from 'properties') the appropriate box to run the file as a program. Clicking it, I am asked to either run it or run in terminal. The second option works as intended, with the terminal asking for my password then running the command.

Is there a way to run the program directly? Currently it doesn't work (presumably because it cannot run the sudo command without password)

Comment: Use `gksu` instead of sudo, it's used for graphical confirmation

Comment: And if you don't want it to ask for the password at all (i.e. have your password in the script itself), look here: [Pass sudo command from GUI](http://askubuntu.com/a/790169)

Comment: @JonasCz One does never store passwords in plain text, not even in scripts.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Replace `sudo` with `gksudo --` in your script, like this:

```
gksudo -- sh -c "sync; echo 3 > /proc/sys/vm/drop_caches"
```

That will open a simple dialogue window to ask for your password instead of prompting you for it on STDERR which is not connected to a terminal if you run the script from your desktop.

On newer releases of Ubuntu, `gksudo` might not be preinstalled any more. If it doesn't work, you will have to install the `gksu` package first, using this command:

```
sudo apt-get install gksu
```

Comment: Although this seems like it should work, it doesn't. I do get the graphical password prompt, but the command doesn't seem to be executed - checking with free -m to check the results, nothing happens when using the shortcut, but it does respond when using the terminal.

Comment: And what happens if you run the gksudo command I gave you in the terminal? Do you get any error/debug messages there? Did you maybe forget the single quotes I added?

Comment: @ByteCommander I don't think you should have quotes around `sh -c` as well, that's `su -c` syntax.

Comment: @muru Try it, if you don't add the quotes, `gksudo` tries to interpret the `-c` as its own argument and fails.

Comment: @ByteCommander Hmm.. Peculiar. It doesn't work in the terminal either. I didn't forget the quotes. I don't get any error message, the graphical prompt appears, I enter the password, but right after (checking with free -m) there is no change in memory. Immediately after, trying sudo sh -c "sync; echo 3 > /proc/sys/vm/drop_caches" works. Is there a problem with the syntax, I wonder...

Comment: @ByteCommander then you should do `gksudo -- sh -c '…'`

Comment: @muru this syntax solved it! It now works as intended. Thanks everyone, I'll mark this as solved