# How to Launch Applications as root by default without using terminal

Tags: permissions, root

Trying to find a  way to launch apps from GUI as root by default without using terminal or command. I have gone through several sites and all says to launch by using "sudo %app name%". But what i am looking for is to launch apps automatically as root by clicking on the graphical icon without having to use terminal each time. Thanks in advance.

Comment: If you are **really** sure you want it (you shouldn't), you can create a `.desktop` file: http://askubuntu.com/questions/281293/creating-a-desktop-file-for-a-new-application and in it using a command with sudo, after configuring it to run without asking a password: http://askubuntu.com/a/147265/16395 . If you do it, keep very good backups (wrong clicks are even easier than wrong command line commands...)

Comment: Are you familiar with `gksu`? It would allow you to create a `.desktop` file with GUI password prompt (for your password , i.e. you need to be in the adm/sudo group).