# Is there a way to pass strings to aliases

Tags: command-line

I want to make an alias for sudo i.e.

```
alias now="echo [password] | sudo -S"
```

but it doesn't seem to work...

I was thinking that something like the following would work

```
alias now="echo [password] | sudo -S ${command_line_parameter}"
```

but I don't know what "${command_line_parameter}" would be... Any ideas?

Comment: Don't even consider doing this - there's already a much better way to [Execute sudo without Password](https://askubuntu.com/a/147265/178692) - which doesn't expose your password in plain text.

Comment: And that's why `sudo` does not read the password from `STDIN`.

Comment: I am the only one using the linux installation. Also, I want to do it just for a laugh and to confuse the hell out of my friends :)

I was half considering using f\*\*\*ing as the alias XD

Answer (score 0):

*This post is  only aimed to answer the how to of your question, however as others suggest it, you should consider implementing your desired rules in `/etc/sudoers` file, something like:*

```
james  ALL=(ALL:ALL) NOPASSWD: /bin/ls
```

---

You can't pass an argument to an `alias` in a way you are doing it, you can use "functions" instead:

```
now(){ echo $1 | sudo -S $@ }
```

and use it like:

```
now password
```

If you want to hardcode your password:

```
now(){ echo your-password | sudo -S $@ }
```

Which non of them are a good thing to do at all, it's like giving your password away.

Comment: I am well aware of the security issues with this but I am the only one using the installation and also, it is within a virtual machine. It is also just as something to be entertaining (while being functional) for me to confuse the hell out of my friends. I could have used f\*\*\*ing as the alias for added fun but... I doubt that would be accepted to have in a question