# how to create dynamic qcow2 image from Windows C:\ drive?

Tags: kvm-virtualization, dd, qemu

I want to convert a Windows 7 C:\ Drive from my previous laptop into a qcow2 image which I wan to use to create a KVM virtual machine from on a new (linux based) computer.

I guess the simplest way would be some sort of `dd` plus a `qemu-img convert`operation.

1.) Boot the old W7 laptop from a live system and run:
`dd if=/dev/sda1 of=/path/to/W7.img`

(would I need to add any `dd` options to make that bootable? any other options [for blocksize i.e.]) recommended?)

2.) On the new machine say something like
`qemu-img convert -f raw -O qcow2 /path/to/W7.img /path/to/W7.qcow2`

that should give me a pretty exact copy with the same size of the C:\ drive I guess.

Now the original C:drive is quite large and half empty, so I'd like to have a dynamically expanding qcow2 image as an end result and likewise reduce it's size.

Is there any option I can add to the `qemu-img convert` operation which would help to achieve that?

Answer (score 1):

There is a tool already available to do this conversion, called [`virt-p2v`](http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/bionic/man1/virt-p2v.1.html).

To get started, install `libguestfs-tools` on your Ubuntu system which will serve as the hypervisor for your new KVM virtual machine. This will install `virt-p2v`, `virt-v2v` and `virt-p2v-make-disk`, all of which you will need.

```
sudo apt install libguestfs-tools
```

Now insert a USB stick to your Linux system, make note of its `/dev/sd*` device name, and run `virt-p2v-make-disk` to create a bootable virt-p2v environment, from which you will later boot the Windows machine. (Or see the [man page](http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/bionic/man1/virt-p2v-make-disk.1.html) for other options for creating the bootable image.)

```
sudo virt-p2v-make-disk -o /dev/sd*
```

Now boot your Windows system from this USB stick. It will ask you to provide credentials to SSH into the Linux machine. You will either need to [enable root](https://askubuntu.com/q/44418/75668) on the Ubuntu machine, or set up [passwordless sudo](https://askubuntu.com/q/147241/75668) for your account.

After you set up ssh, virt-p2v will ask you some questions about the virtual machine you want to create, and then it will begin copying data from your physical machine to the Ubuntu server.

Comment: sorry, for slow response. I was stuck in "can't load external javascript hell" .... now, sounds like a pretty sophisticated tool. but I am missing the part that makes the size of the qcow2 image smaller then the actually 102 GB of the physical drive. Is that built in?

Comment: regarding `qemu-img convert` I came across  the `-c` option which may 'compress' the new file and (maybe also create a (sizewise) dynamic qcow2 image.

Comment: @vrms The image you get should already be sparse, but if it isn't, you can use `virt-sparsify` to fix that. As for actually shrinking it, that's probably something you should do with Windows tools _before_ `p2v`ing it.

Comment: you mean shrinking the existing physical C:\ drive rahter then trying to shrink an image file I guess. Sounds much more risky that way to me but maybe there is not other way?

Comment: Or, at least, shrinking the partition(s). The virtual disk can then be shrunk to match later.

Answer (score 0):

Another way is to connect the laptop drive (I used a M2 storage to sata adapter - careful there are M2 pci adapters too that wont work. Or through network.)

Create a VM based on a raw partition. Both Virt-manager and VBox can do this. It is very safe and stable, have been using Windows from a raw partition for a while inside Ubuntu with no issues, but you could also copy the partition or use KDE Part-mgr to back it up to file. Windows likes having its partition table present, so use the whole drive /dev/sdX.

Then attach Clonezilla ISO to the VM, as well as a target storage location for the Qcow2, boot the ISO and it will clone the drive to a file. I believe it can do the reverse as well.

EDIT: I just confirmed using dd to copy a whole Windows drive and then qemu-img to convert it to qcow2 does work. https://moozing.wordpress.com/2015/06/24/converting-a-physical-machine-to-a-virtual-machine/

Both that and the Clonezilla p2v worked. Its important to get the EFI working in the VM manager. Heres some info on how to do that with VMM/KVM: https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/612813/virt-manager-change-firmware-after-installation

And heres some links to clarify the midly unclear restore step with CLoneZilla (The step that has notes: "Do not go any further into the folders. Press tab twice and enter to select Done"):
https://support.onlogic.com/documentation/linux-clonezilla/ 
https://clonezilla.org/clonezilla-live-doc.php