# How can i pass the sudo password as an argument in my command?

Tags: command-line, bash, sudo

My command is

```
echo "deb http://www.apache.org/dist/cassandra/debian 311x main" | sudo tee -a /etc/apt/sources.list.d/cassandra.sources.list
```

I want to pass my password `user-password` as an argument in the above command similar to the one shown below:

```
echo user-password | sudo -S apt-get update
```

My issue is that i don't know how to pass both the URL as well as the sudo password simultaneously.

Also i am ensuring that the password is not visible on the terminal as this command will be called by a python script which reads the password from a file (or from user)

Comment: **To Close Voters** and @Melebius this isn't a question about calling `sudo` and using the password as a parameter. The OP already has this part figured out. This is a question about piping to `sudo tee` with an extra argument `-S` and where does the `echo <password>` get placed in this chain?

Comment: @WinEunuuchs2Unix I (as one of the close voters) don’t agree. I think the question is an [XY problem](http://xyproblem.info/) and if the question is not a duplicate, OP should clarify their actual needs, particularly why editing `sudoers` is not acceptable in their case. I believe using plaintext password on the command line should be avoided.

Comment: @Melebius Seeing Muru's answer below it's safe to say it's not a duplicate. Calling it an XY problem doesn't seem right unless you can get the same output as Muru's answer using a different process that doesn't involve a password. Yours or my believe about someone going about something the wrong way ie. "plain text password in CLI" isn't justification for closing ie "I don't like that" isn't a close vote option. I guess when all else fails that's what down voting is for.

Comment: @ Aksh Using password in plain text on the command line or in scripts should be generally avoided, see https://askubuntu.com/q/147241/250300 for other options. What are you trying to achieve? Do you want to use that line in a script? @WinEunuuchs2Unix OK, you’re right I prematurely called this question a duplicate. Now I am requalifying it to “unclear what you’re asking” and therefore not retracting my close vote now.

Answer (score 0):

Shuffle the command a bit, moving the `echo` for the source inside the `sudo` command:

```
echo password | sudo -S sh -c 'echo "deb http://www.apache.org/dist/cassandra/debian 311x main" >> /etc/apt/sources.list.d/cassandra.sources.list'
```

Comment: I wouldn’t recommend providing a password on the command line. See https://stackoverflow.com/q/3830823/711006 for details.

Comment: Neither would I, but there are uses for it.

Comment: Put a space before "echo"; otherwise it will be exposed to "history". And "ps" will always show it. A redirect should be the better method.