# Bash skips password prompt

Tags: 18.04, bash, sudo

I have the following little script:

```
#!/bin/bash
cd ~

thunderbird &
firefox &

sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get upgrade
```

It worked for the last two years, but for a few days it skips the password prompt. Output (without any actions from me, except starting the script):

```
me@UBUNTU:~$ sh goodmorningscript.sh 
[sudo] password for me: 
[sudo] password for me: 
me@UBUNTU:~$
```

It just runs through, without stopping and waiting on the password prompt.
I don't want a solution [without entering my password](https://askubuntu.com/q/147241/613564).

What could have caused my Ubuntu to skip the prompt and how can I solve it?

Note: If I manually enter `sudo` commands, the prompt works as expected.

---

GNU bash, version 4.4.19(1)-release (x86_64-pc-linux-gnu)

Ubuntu 18.04.1 LTS

---

I found one possible solution, that works in my case. If the `sudo` command comes before the ones with `&`, the password prompt works as expected:

```
#!/bin/bash
cd ~

sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get upgrade

thunderbird &
firefox &
```

I still don't know why, but maybe this helps.

Comment: Do the `apt-get` commands actually run? or do you just see two password prompts and then nothing? Is the behavior different if you run the script directly `./goodmorningscript.sh` rather than via `sh`?

Comment: `apt-get` commands run as expected (with pw-prompt). If I run it with `./` it behaves the same.

Answer (score 1):

I had the same problem when using the terminal. Just restarting the terminal fixed it for me.

Comment: Yep!  I just had the same problem (not inside a script, just executing a command) and a terminal restart fixed it.  Not sure what caused it.

Answer (score -1):

It is most likely that you have used `sudo` (with some other command) before executing your script.

`sudo` effect stays for a while (default 15 minutes).
Try waiting for a couple of minutes. Or close and reopen your terminal and try again.

If the same behaviour persists a bit more information will be required in that case. Run `sudo -l` and paste the output here

Comment: I think this would be better suited for a comment at this point, as we don't yet have enough information...

Comment: I don't think there would be a password prompt in that case

Comment: It is the first thing I execute in the terminal, so there is no `sudo` from earier.