# allowing all users to execute kill command on kubuntu 20.04LTS

Tags: permissions, sudo

on kubuntu 20lts

sudo sh -c ' echo "ALL  ALL=(NOPASSWD: /usr/bin/kill" >> /etc/sudoers'

I have some machines with Kubuntu 20.04 LTS, everyday when the machines start, and the users login, smb4k mounts shares. But sometimes some shares dont mount because mounthelper hangs up. I need to allow all users to execute the kill command in a bash script to remote them All the shares.

But it doesn't work... -bash: kill: (1709) - operation not permitted
The process is owned by root
What I'm doing wrong?

Comment: All users *can* use the `kill` command. Can you be more specific and give some examples of the actual problems you are experiencing?

Comment: `kill` is located in `/bin/kill` not `/usr/bin/kill`. Giving anyone possibility to kill any process is from security reasons a bad idea. Maybe allow only specific users or group.

Comment: @Mateusz in  a "unified" system, `/bin` is symlinked to `usr/bin` so that is as expected.

Comment: I have some machines with kubuntu 20lts, everyday when the machine start and the user's login, smb4k mount shares. But sometimes some shadows didn't mount because mountheper hungs. I need to allow all users to execute the kill command in a bash script to remote them All shares
My /etc/sudoers is
ALL ALL=NOPASSWD: /use/bin/kill
But it doesn't work... -bash: kill: (1709) - operación no permitida
The process is owned by root...  What I'm doing wrong?

Comment: @vanadium you're right. I didn't realize it's now a symlink. My Kubuntu 20.04 was upgraded from previous version and it still has separated `/bin` and `/usr/bin`

Comment: Wheris kill...   in usr bin...  Please help, I can't find the problem

Comment: Note that when you run `kill` in a terminal, you're likely getting your shell's builtin `kill` command, rather than an external executable  `/bin/kill` or `/usr/bin/kill`. When you run `sudo kill` you **will** get the external command.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The only thing you are currently doing wrong is assuming that there is no need anymore to precede the command with `sudo`.

All users *by default* are already allowed to use the `kill` command. However, users only can kill processes they owned. To kill a process owned by root, users must precede the `kill` command by `sudo` to have it run with elevated permissions.

The change you performed to `/etc/sudoers` will allow them to execute `sudo kill` without having to enter a password. See [Execute sudo without Password?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/147241/execute-sudo-without-password)

Comment: Thanks it's true, this is the error