# How to write a shell script that will reload terminal at middle of the script and then start using commands again?

Tags: command-line, bash, scripts, java, ubuntu-sdk

I recently knew about [sdkman](https://sdkman.io) in [gitpod.io](https://gitpod.io) and I wanna install different java versions using this manager. But I have a very old version of sdkman. That's I need to update it, then install java. But I don't wanna type this commands in my every repository in gitpod. That's why I have written an shell script `prerequisites.sh` and I will use this file in every repository. The script is:-

```
sdk update
sdk install java 17-open

# there are lots of command under this, but they're not necessary in this question.
```

But then I knew that after updating sdkman, I need to restart terminal. I found that `exec bash` restarts terminal. But when I add `exec bash` in my shell script, it doesn't execute the commands below the `exec bash` command. Can someone suggest me, how to do this?

```
sdk update
exec bash #recently added, but doesn't execute the commands after it :(
sdk install java 17-open
```

Comment: How can it help me??

Answer (score 0):

The problem you are having is when you open a new shell or restart the current shell, your script will no longer be loaded in the new shell. So, what you need to do is:

1. Open the parent shell
2. Execute the first command
3. Create a child shell within the parent script
4. This child shell will be loaded with the new environment parameters
5. Execute the second command within the child shell
6. Exit child shell
7. Exit parent shell

For the above mentioned commands, you can use something like this.

```
#!/bin/bash
sdk update
sudo su - $USER -c 'sdk install java 17-open'
```

The first command will run in the parent shell.
The second line (with sudod su - $USER) will open a new child shell within the same script, and execute the second command.

PS: You will be asked to enter the password, if you haven't configured "NOPASSWD" for sudo. Check [this](https://askubuntu.com/questions/147241/execute-sudo-without-password) to setup that.