# Passwordless Login to Ubunto 20.04 with FIDO2

Tags: password, authentication, two-factor-authentication

So i've setup passwordless thru FIDO2 by adding

`auth sufficient pam_u2f.so authfile=/home/me/.config/FIDO2/u2f_keys`

having followed the instructions on the yubico page to generate the u2f_keys code

It's working great as an **additional** factor of authentication but I'd like it to be the only one (ie, we are going passwordless) or at least the primary form of authentication. Right now logging in and sudo'ing results in it asking for a password and then asking to tap the key.

Comment: See here to disable the sudo password: https://askubuntu.com/questions/147241/execute-sudo-without-password Then set the keyring password blank, and enable autologin.

Comment: Enabling auto login would bypass FIDO2 I'm pretty sure..

Comment: A year late, I know, but where did you put that auth line? At the beginning or at the end? Similar worked for me when it was before the ones that checked password.