# remove password: for sudo, for user, for root

Tags: password

I have a complex password in Ubuntu
So I don't want to ask for my password every time
Is there a way
I want to disable it because it asks me to enter the password in everything, install programs, give commands, and even when opening or closing the system

Comment: Do you know that you can change the password? Type `passwd` in a terminal.

Comment: You should check your setup, since a DE usually does not ask for your password on "closing" (whatever that is) the system. On login you need to change the GDM configuration. Would be easier to change your passwd btw.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Execute sudo without Password?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/147241/execute-sudo-without-password)

Answer (score -2):

```
sudo visudo
```

put the NOPASSWD:ALL everywhere:

```
#User alias specification
yourusername ALL=(ALL) NOPASSWD:ALL

# User privilege specification
root    ALL=(ALL:ALL) NOPASSWD: ALL

# Members of the admin group may gain root privileges
%admin ALL=(ALL) NOPASSWD: ALL

# Allow members of group sudo to execute any command
%sudo   ALL=(ALL:ALL) NOPASSWD: ALL
```

It will still bug you about a password when installing software. I still do not know how to remove that ..