# andy ALL=(ALL) NOPASSWD: ALL is not working

Tags: permissions, sudo

I want to run privileged commands with having to enter my password.

I edited sudoers using the recommendation here.

[Execute sudo without Password?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/147241/execute-sudo-without-password)

But I still have to enter my password?

```
# User privilege specification
root    ALL=(ALL:ALL) ALL

andy ALL=(ALL) ALL

andy ALL=(ALL) NOPASSWD: ALL
```

Comment: Please use the search function before asking a new question about a common topic. Thanks.

Comment: @Artur Meinild I did use the search and used the recommendation I found. andy ALL=(ALL) NOPASSWD: ALL

Comment: Did you put it at the very bottom of the sudoers file? And did you log out and in again?

Comment: Yes, I put it at the bottom. Log out and rebooted as well. @Artur Meinild

Comment: Did you try `andy ALL=(ALL:ALL) NOPASSWD: ALL`? I'm using this syntax, and it's working without any issues.

Comment: @Artur Meinild I tried it. But when I use gparted it still asks for password. I will just restore sudoers to it's original condition. Thanks for your help.

Comment: Gparted? Afaik, GUI programs does not use `sudo`, but instead uses polkit. You're basically asking why you don't succeed in drilling a hole with a hammer ... 