# How to set static IP address?

Tags: networking, virtualbox-networking

I have configured network adapter of guest Ubuntu to work in a bridged mode so I could ssh to it from the host machine.

The problem is that the guest Ubuntu ip address keep changing.

Even though it changes 
within a very short range 192.168.0.4-10 it is still takes time to configure Putty and other programs each time.

Is there a way to make the guest Ubuntu ip address to be static?

My guest OS has the full GUI.

Answer (score 35, accepted):

To give static ip address graphically

1.Go to `network connections`

2.Then edit the connections in the wired settings

3.Add the ip address for the system

Here are the images below

[image: Network Connections]

[image: Network-connections![]

If you are curious, You can find newly created connection from the above steps as configurations file at  `/etc/NetworkManager/system-connections`

Comment: You are the champion. With you answer I managed to configure my Ubuntu and Fedora in a seconds. Though I had to restar the Fedora.

Comment: Happy to Help :D

Comment: the save button is not enabled. What should be the ip address of DNS servers.

Comment: This was a temporary solution for me. It worked while I struggled to configure two routers to work together. Then it failed and I had to switch back to automatic DHCP. BTW, the Ziggo/Cisco EPC3925 wireless/cableTV gateway/router is a flaming POS.

Answer (score 31):

Edit `/etc/network/interfaces` to reflect something like this:

```
# This file describes the network interfaces available on your system
# and how to activate them. For more information, see interfaces(5).

# The loopback network interface
auto lo
iface lo inet loopback

# The primary network interface
auto eth0
iface eth0 inet static
address 192.168.0.X
netmask 255.255.255.0
network 192.168.0.0
broadcast 192.168.0.255
gateway 192.168.0.X
dns-nameservers 192.168.0.X
```

Then do a:

```
sudo /etc/init.d/networking restart
```

And that will get you fixed up.

Comment: @Mitten if this answer solved your question pleas mark it as accepted!

Comment: Correction: /etc/network/interfaces. Also, if the static address is routable (in DNS, instead of e.g. 192.168.x.x), edit /etc/hosts and /etc/hostname to match.

Comment: i have ens33, so should i change eth0 to ens33 , should i restart the system

Answer (score 10):

OP posted:

> #### Setting Static IP
>
> ```
> sudo nano /etc/network/interfaces #  I use vi instead of nano
> ```
>
> When you open up the interfaces doc, you will see something like this:
>
> ```
> auto lo eth0
> iface lo inet loopback
> iface eth0 inet dynamic
> ```
>
> You want to change it to incorporate the following:
>
> ```
> auto lo eth0
> iface lo inet loopback
> iface eth0 inet static
>         address xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx (enter your ip here)
>         netmask xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx (mine was 255.255.255.0)
>         gateway xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx (enter gateway ip here,usually the address of the router)
> ```
>
> Save your changes and exit.
>
> Then I needed to add some dns info to `resolv.conf` so I opened up the
>   file like so:
>
> ```
> sudo nano /etc/resolv.conf # I use vi instead of nano
> ```
>
> Initially this file is empty excluding a warning of "Do not put
>   anything in here it will be overwritten". I added the following
>   information none the less.
>
> This is the format:
>
> ```
> nameserver xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx(enter your dns server ip)
> nameserver xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx(enter your alt dns server ip)
> ```
>
> This is what I entered:
>
> ```
> nameserver 8.8.8.8 
> nameserver 8.8.4.4
> ```
>
> Save your changes and exit.
>
> At this point you can either restart networking:
>
> ```
> sudo /etc/init.d/networking restart
> ```
>
> or reboot which is what I did:
>
> ```
> sudo reboot
> ```
>
> Once I was logged back in I tried the install again of `pure-ftpd` and
>   all is good:
>
> ```
> apt-get install pure-ftpd
> ```
>
> I hope this helps someone, I looked around for the fix and just
>   happened upon it by accident.

Comment: Community wiki or something? :)

Answer (score 2):

On Ubuntu 18.04 LTS and Ubuntu 20, **Netplan** is available and replaced *ifupdown* by default. Let's say our interface is *ens192*. To check whether it's being managed by NetworkManager:

```
cat /run/NetworkManager/conf.d/netplan.conf
```

Which could output this:

```
[keyfile]
# devices managed by networkd
unmanaged-devices+=interface-name:ens192,
```

Backup the configuration file (your path or file may be different):

```
cp /etc/netplan/01-netcfg.yaml /etc/netplan/01-netcfg.yaml.ori
```

Then edit `/etc/netplan/01-netcfg.yaml` to look something like:

```
# This file describes the network interfaces available on your system
# For more information, see netplan(5).
network:
  version: 2
  ethernets:
    ens192:
      dhcp4: false
      wakeonlan: true
      addresses:
        - 192.168.14.2/24
      gateway4: 192.168.14.1
      nameservers:
        addresses: [8.8.8.8]
```

Generate the output file with debug for extra details:

```
sudo netplan --debug generate
```

We'd like to see:

```
DEBUG:command generate: running ['/lib/netplan/generate']
** (generate:9991): DEBUG: 18:08:30.447: Processing input file //etc/netplan/01-netcfg.yaml..
** (generate:9991): DEBUG: 18:08:30.447: starting new processing pass
** (generate:9991): DEBUG: 18:08:30.448: ens192: setting default backend to 1
** (generate:9991): DEBUG: 18:08:30.448: Generating output files..
** (generate:9991): DEBUG: 18:08:30.449: NetworkManager: definition ens192 is not for us (backend 1)
```

We can see the actual configuration with:

```
cat /run/systemd/network/10-netplan-ens192.network
```

Let's make it active by:

```
sudo systemctl restart systemd-networkd
```

Be prepared to lose the connection if doing this over SSH. Do `man netplan` for details. There is also a [related answer](https://askubuntu.com/questions/961552/need-example-netplan-yaml-for-static-ip) on this site. See also the [documentation](https://ubuntu.com/server/docs/network-configuration).

Answer (score 1):

It seems the interface `eth0` was configured before and the address was kept persistently (for some reason) by the kernel.

To clear all addresses from interface `eth0` without having to restart network services or bringing the interface up/down :

```
sudo ip addr flush dev eth0
```

Then you can use ifup to configure eth0 by reading `/etc/network/interfaces` file :

```
sudo ifup eth0
```

For verbosity :

```
sudo ifup -v eth0
```

Answer (score 0):

The only thing that worked for me was:

- go into modem config (`http://192.168.0.1`)
- set up DHCP Reservation Lease: it maps LAN IPs to MAC addresses
- set the interface to use DHCP (the default, modifiable on NetworkManager at `nm-connection-editor`)

Comment: This is not an answer, but a workaround only if the router belongs to the user.

Answer (score 0):

==== Configure static IP on Ubuntu 14.04

in file /etc/network/interfaces

```
iface eth0 inet static
address 10.193.36.29
netmask 255.255.255.0
gateway 10.193.36.1
dns-nameservers 10.124.31.140  10.213.134.41  10.72.255.100
```

then:

```
sudo ifup eth0
```

need some time to take effect