# how to set a static ip on ubuntu 14.04 which is runing on wmware workstation 10.

Tags: networking, vmware, vmware-workstation

i configured master and slave setup. but some times after restart the machines wired ip address changes. how to set a static ip step by step. please help me thank you.

Comment: This question might have better answers: http://askubuntu.com/questions/338442/how-to-set-static-ip-address-in-guest-ubuntu-running-in-virtual-box?rq=1

Answer (score 0):

1. sudo -s
2. ip link show
3. chose your network interface
4. nano /etc/network/interfaces
5. `allow-hotplug nameOfYourNetworkInterface
   iface nameOfYourNetworkInterface inet static
       address yourIPAddress
       netmask yourMask
       gateway yourGateway
       dns-nameservers IPAddressOfYourDNSServer IPAddressOfYourSecondDNSServer`