# Do you really need to remove DHCP clients for static IP to stick?

Tags: networking, server, dns, dhcp, static-ip

The instruction from [this link](http://www.howtogeek.com/howto/ubuntu/change-ubuntu-server-from-dhcp-to-a-static-ip-address/) works to change from DHCP dynamic IP to static. But there's a step where it says:

> You need to also remove the dhcp client for this to stick (thanks to
>   Peter for noticing). You might need to remove dhcp-client3 instead.

And then:

```
sudo apt-get remove dhcp-client
```

**Is that really necessary? If so why? Is there any other way without removing `dhcp-client`?**

Comment: Reading through this "how-to" (Dr. Evil air quotes), I get the distinct feeling the author does not really know what he's talking about... He seems to adopt several "tips" (air quotes again) from the comments without further ado.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, you don't need to do that. Refer to [this other answer](https://askubuntu.com/q/338442/295286) on askubuntu site

I personally use the following bit of code in `/etc/dhcp/dhclient.conf` file on my home PC which has a USB wireless dongle attached to it:

```
interface "wlan0" {
    send dhcp-requested-address 192.168.0.222;

}
```

As you can see, the PC always asks for 192.168.0.222 address.

Answer (score 0):

i have never removed the dhcp-client for a static lease. if you edit the interfaces file to make your eth0, or which eth you are configuring, static. It should work after a reboot or a network restart.

So imho no you don't have to remove it... hope it helps