# wifi cannot get dhcp but can get dhcp with cable connection on same wifi router

Tags: 14.04, wireless

I'm not sure how this is happening on my freshly installed ubuntu 14.04

```
$ tail -50 /var/log/syslog 
Oct 17 10:43:47 P45VJ NetworkManager[1119]: <info> (wlan0): DHCPv4 state changed nbi -> preinit
Oct 17 10:43:47 P45VJ dhclient: Listening on LPF/wlan0/6c:71:d9:8b:3e:e5
Oct 17 10:43:47 P45VJ dhclient: Sending on   LPF/wlan0/6c:71:d9:8b:3e:e5
Oct 17 10:43:47 P45VJ dhclient: Sending on   Socket/fallback
Oct 17 10:43:47 P45VJ dhclient: DHCPDISCOVER on wlan0 to 255.255.255.255 port 67 interval 3 (xid=0x875cf62f)
Oct 17 10:43:48 P45VJ avahi-daemon[1017]: Joining mDNS multicast group on interface wlan0.IPv6 with address fe80::6e71:d9ff:fe8b:3ee5.
Oct 17 10:43:48 P45VJ avahi-daemon[1017]: New relevant interface wlan0.IPv6 for mDNS.
Oct 17 10:43:48 P45VJ avahi-daemon[1017]: Registering new address record for fe80::6e71:d9ff:fe8b:3ee5 on wlan0.*.
Oct 17 10:43:50 P45VJ dhclient: DHCPDISCOVER on wlan0 to 255.255.255.255 port 67 interval 3 (xid=0x875cf62f)
Oct 17 10:43:53 P45VJ dhclient: DHCPDISCOVER on wlan0 to 255.255.255.255 port 67 interval 4 (xid=0x875cf62f)
Oct 17 10:43:57 P45VJ dhclient: DHCPDISCOVER on wlan0 to 255.255.255.255 port 67 interval 8 (xid=0x875cf62f)
Oct 17 10:44:05 P45VJ dhclient: DHCPDISCOVER on wlan0 to 255.255.255.255 port 67 interval 11 (xid=0x875cf62f)
Oct 17 10:44:08 P45VJ NetworkManager[1119]: <info> (wlan0): IP6 addrconf timed out or failed.
Oct 17 10:44:08 P45VJ NetworkManager[1119]: <info> Activation (wlan0) Stage 4 of 5 (IPv6 Configure Timeout) scheduled...
Oct 17 10:44:08 P45VJ NetworkManager[1119]: <info> Activation (wlan0) Stage 4 of 5 (IPv6 Configure Timeout) started...
Oct 17 10:44:08 P45VJ NetworkManager[1119]: <info> Activation (wlan0) Stage 4 of 5 (IPv6 Configure Timeout) complete.
Oct 17 10:44:16 P45VJ dhclient: DHCPDISCOVER on wlan0 to 255.255.255.255 port 67 interval 8 (xid=0x875cf62f)
Oct 17 10:44:24 P45VJ dhclient: DHCPDISCOVER on wlan0 to 255.255.255.255 port 67 interval 20 (xid=0x875cf62f)
Oct 17 10:44:33 P45VJ NetworkManager[1119]: <warn> (wlan0): DHCPv4 request timed out.
Oct 17 10:44:33 P45VJ NetworkManager[1119]: <info> (wlan0): canceled DHCP transaction, DHCP client pid 2264
Oct 17 10:44:33 P45VJ NetworkManager[1119]: <info> Activation (wlan0) Stage 4 of 5 (IPv4 Configure Timeout) scheduled...
Oct 17 10:44:33 P45VJ NetworkManager[1119]: <info> Activation (wlan0) Stage 4 of 5 (IPv4 Configure Timeout) started...
Oct 17 10:44:33 P45VJ NetworkManager[1119]: <info> (wlan0): device state change: ip-config -> failed (reason 'ip-config-unavailable') [70 120 5]
Oct 17 10:44:33 P45VJ NetworkManager[1119]: <info> NetworkManager state is now DISCONNECTED
Oct 17 10:44:33 P45VJ NetworkManager[1119]: <warn> Activation (wlan0) failed for connection 'ROHANI_WIFI'
Oct 17 10:44:33 P45VJ NetworkManager[1119]: <info> Activation (wlan0) Stage 4 of 5 (IPv4 Configure Timeout) complete.
Oct 17 10:44:33 P45VJ NetworkManager[1119]: <info> (wlan0): device state change: failed -> disconnected (reason 'none') [120 30 0]
Oct 17 10:44:33 P45VJ NetworkManager[1119]: <info> (wlan0): deactivating device (reason 'none') [0]
Oct 17 10:44:33 P45VJ avahi-daemon[1017]: Withdrawing address record for fe80::6e71:d9ff:fe8b:3ee5 on wlan0.
Oct 17 10:44:33 P45VJ avahi-daemon[1017]: Leaving mDNS multicast group on interface wlan0.IPv6 with address fe80::6e71:d9ff:fe8b:3ee5.
Oct 17 10:44:33 P45VJ avahi-daemon[1017]: Interface wlan0.IPv6 no longer relevant for mDNS.
Oct 17 10:44:33 P45VJ kernel: [  127.298376] wlan0: deauthenticating from b0:c5:54:ae:f8:f4 by local choice (reason=3)
Oct 17 10:44:33 P45VJ wpa_supplicant[1170]: wlan0: CTRL-EVENT-DISCONNECTED bssid=b0:c5:54:ae:f8:f4 reason=3 locally_generated=1
Oct 17 10:44:33 P45VJ NetworkManager[1119]: <warn> Connection disconnected (reason -3)
Oct 17 10:44:33 P45VJ NetworkManager[1119]: <info> (wlan0): supplicant interface state: completed -> disconnected
Oct 17 10:44:33 P45VJ kernel: [  127.307378] cfg80211: Calling CRDA to update world regulatory domain
Oct 17 10:44:33 P45VJ wpa_supplicant[1170]: wlan0: CTRL-EVENT-SCAN-STARTED 
Oct 17 10:44:33 P45VJ NetworkManager[1119]: <warn> Connection disconnected (reason -3)
Oct 17 10:44:33 P45VJ kernel: [  127.316586] cfg80211: World regulatory domain updated:
Oct 17 10:44:33 P45VJ kernel: [  127.316590] cfg80211:   (start_freq - end_freq @ bandwidth), (max_antenna_gain, max_eirp)
Oct 17 10:44:33 P45VJ kernel: [  127.316593] cfg80211:   (2402000 KHz - 2472000 KHz @ 40000 KHz), (300 mBi, 2000 mBm)
Oct 17 10:44:33 P45VJ kernel: [  127.316596] cfg80211:   (2457000 KHz - 2482000 KHz @ 40000 KHz), (300 mBi, 2000 mBm)
Oct 17 10:44:33 P45VJ kernel: [  127.316597] cfg80211:   (2474000 KHz - 2494000 KHz @ 20000 KHz), (300 mBi, 2000 mBm)
Oct 17 10:44:33 P45VJ kernel: [  127.316599] cfg80211:   (5170000 KHz - 5250000 KHz @ 40000 KHz), (300 mBi, 2000 mBm)
Oct 17 10:44:33 P45VJ kernel: [  127.316601] cfg80211:   (5735000 KHz - 5835000 KHz @ 40000 KHz), (300 mBi, 2000 mBm)
Oct 17 10:44:34 P45VJ avahi-daemon[1017]: Joining mDNS multicast group on interface wlan0.IPv6 with address fe80::6e71:d9ff:fe8b:3ee5.
Oct 17 10:44:34 P45VJ avahi-daemon[1017]: New relevant interface wlan0.IPv6 for mDNS.
Oct 17 10:44:34 P45VJ avahi-daemon[1017]: Registering new address record for fe80::6e71:d9ff:fe8b:3ee5 on wlan0.*.
Oct 17 10:44:36 P45VJ wpa_supplicant[1170]: wlan0: Reject scan trigger since one is already pending
Oct 17 10:44:59 P45VJ wpa_supplicant[1170]: wlan0: CTRL-EVENT-SCAN-STARTED
```

Comment: If that's only your wifi, but not the others, try setting up static IP as shown in my answer here http://askubuntu.com/a/682910/295286  . I had a somewhat similar issue after messing around with dhcp - my home router wouldn't give my laptop dynamic ip, but would give static one.

Comment: how to do this only on a specific wifi network?

Comment: I tried giving it satic IP with NetworkManager GUI (network icon top right), it got the designated IP but even unable to ping the gateway (wifi router)

Comment: did you also give it a dns ? When you select "manual" configuration, you also need to provide DNS server; for example , opendsn 208.67.220.220, or google public dns 8.8.8.8.  As for doing it only on specific wifi network with dhclient.conf file . . . i am researching that right now, will let you know if i find anything

Comment: yes. I used 8.8.8.8 but even it's gateway cannot be reached. I even tried disabling hwcrypt on /etc/modprobe.d/ath9k.conf (atheros 4562 device)

Comment: my mistake atheros AR9462  device

Comment: did you tried to reboot the router? try to clear everything up and do `dhclient wlan0`. and make sure IPv6 sets only to link local.

Comment: ipv6 link local does not seem to work also. dhclient wlan0 ended with Oct 17 14:18:41 P45VJ avahi-autoipd(wlan0)[9136]: Successfully claimed IP address 169.254.10.54

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was very surprised that after changing wifi security on my dlink router's security to wpa2-tkip, I finally able to connect and get internet access. Definately a weird behavior.