# Set up static IP

Tags: networking

In https://askubuntu.com/a/470245/1471

1. > You will need you need to change `/etc/network/interfaces` to:
   >
   > ```
   > auto eth0
   > iface eth0 inet static
   >    address 10.253.0.50
   >    netmask 255.255.255.0
   >    network 10.253.0.0
   >    gateway 10.253.0.1
   >    dns-nameservers 8.8.8.8
   > ```

   what do the first and second lines mean? In particular, what do
   `auto`, `iface`, and `inet` mean?

   What does `network` mean?

   Is `gateway` the router?
2. > You will have to change the numbers around depending on you network, but **you can find out the information by checking out
   >   ipconfig from Windows**.

   Can I find out the dns-nameservers, gateway, network, netmaskt, and
   address in Ubuntu, instead of in Windows?
3. Is there an alternative way of setting up static IP, instead of
   editing `etc/network/interfaces`? For example, provide the settings as arguments to some commands?

Comment: This configuration file is now deprecated in flawor of [systemd-networkd(8)](http://www.freedesktop.org/software/systemd/man/systemd.network.html)

Comment: This is much easier -> http://askubuntu.com/a/682910/295286

Answer (score 5):

`auto eth0`  : This is [Link layer](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Link_layer) option that will  start the interface(s) at booting of system automatically.

`iface eth0` : `iface` is suffix of defining interface and  creates a stanza called eth0 on an Ethernet device.This is [Network layer](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Network_layer) option.

`inet` and `inet6` is version of ip protocol:

`inet` : IPv4 protocol 
 `inet6` : IPv6 protocol

`inet static` : Defines a static IP address of interface.

`inet dhcp` : It get IP address from DHCP protocol.

`inet manual` : It Does not define an IP address for an interface. Generally used by interfaces that are bridge , aggregation members,VLAN device configured on them etc.

> What does network mean?

`network` : It define class of Network like A,B,C etc. in which IP address belong to .you can learn more about network and class from [here](https://www.debian.org/doc/manuals/network-administrator/ch-tcpip.html) and [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Classful_network)

> Is gateway the router?

No, gateway can be any where all data/packet pass through to go somewhere and router used to communicate two or more different network.

> Can I find out the dns-nameservers, gateway, network, netmask, and
>   address in Ubuntu, instead of in Windows?

For IP address,netmask,MAC address, Broadcast IP use command :

`ifconfig` : It will print all interface IP

`ifconfig eth0` : It will print only particular interface `eth0` IP

For dns-nameservers you can see in `/etc/resolv.conf` file

For gateway use command:

```
route -n
```

or

```
netstat -nr
```

> Is there an alternative way of setting up static IP, instead of
>   editing etc/network/interfaces

if you are using Ubuntu server then you can use @kyodake answer or other but if you are using Ubuntu Desktop environment then you can

```
System setting -->  Network --> Wired --> options --> IP4 settings
```

[image: pic]

you can take help from [here](https://wiki.debian.org/NetworkConfiguration)

Comment: thanks. what is `inet`? What did you mean by `network`?

Comment: `inet` and `inet6` is version of ip protocol:
 `inet` : IPv4 protocol 
 `inet6` : IPv6 protocol. i have added this in answer.

Comment: `route` or `netstat` may list  multiple gateways, how do you choose which one to use for static IP?

Comment: it list which interface and ip have what gateway.  if any  network shows gateway 0.0.0.0 means default gateway will use(generally default gatway is first line of output ) . otherwise every network have gateway if multiple entry then upper entry will used as gateway

Comment: if you want to change gateway command line then you can change also. you can understand more from http://www.thegeekstuff.com/2012/04/route-examples/  and http://askubuntu.com/questions/168033/how-to-set-static-routes-in-ubuntu-server

Comment: THanks. Can you give examples for explaining " if any network shows gateway 0.0.0.0 means default gateway will use(generally default gatway is first line of output )"  and "otherwise every network have gateway if multiple entry then upper entry will used as gateway"?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/30669/discussion-between-pl-rock-and-tim).

Answer (score 1):

Is there an alternative way of setting up static IP, instead of editing `etc/network/interfaces`?

Yes:

If you connect via a regular UTP cable to your router, and assuming you have DHCP enabled do the following:

```
sudo -i
ip link set dev eth0 down
dhclient eth0
```

This will bring your eth0 up by using DHCP and your network is now configured.

If you don't have DHCP enabled configure your network by issueing the commands below, the gateway address is the IP address of your router. And your IP should be in the same range as the router is.

```
sudo -i
ip addr add 10.10.1.14/24 dev eth0
ip link set dev eth0 up
ip route add default via 10.10.1.1
```

These commands configure your interface but these changes will not survive a reboot, since the information is not stored anyhwere.

## [Source](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/NetworkConfigurationCommandLine/Automatic)