# Ethernet not working after update 14.04 (64 bit)

Tags: 14.04, networking, internet, ethernet, ip

After updating Ubuntu a few days back my ethernet has stopped working. The wifi works fine. I even managed to make my ethernet work once using ***sudo dhclient eth0*** but could not replicate it after reboot. I have another laptop with Windows and the physical cable is fine.

My ethernet connection gets connected but internet doesn't work.
Also I am behind a proxy if that helps in anyway.

I have posted this after reading a lot of fixes on the internet. None of them seem to even temporarily fix my problem.

Any help would be appreciated.

Here are a few outputs :

**ifconfig**

```
eth0  Link encap:Ethernet  HWaddr 14:dd:a9:0d:88:29  
      inet addr:172.24.136.242  Bcast:172.24.143.255  Mask:255.255.248.0
      inet6 addr: fe80::16dd:a9ff:fe0d:8829/64 Scope:Link
      UP BROADCAST RUNNING MULTICAST  MTU:1500  Metric:1
      RX packets:0 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 frame:0
      TX packets:1443 errors:0 dropped:3302 overruns:0 carrier:0
      collisions:0 txqueuelen:1000 
      RX bytes:0 (0.0 B)  TX bytes:161427 (161.4 KB)

lo    Link encap:Local Loopback  
      inet addr:127.0.0.1  Mask:255.0.0.0
      inet6 addr: ::1/128 Scope:Host
      UP LOOPBACK RUNNING  MTU:65536  Metric:1
      RX packets:28333 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 frame:0
      TX packets:28333 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 carrier:0
      collisions:0 txqueuelen:0 
      RX bytes:2407338 (2.4 MB)  TX bytes:2407338 (2.4 MB)

wlan0 Link encap:Ethernet  HWaddr 34:02:86:96:f3:98  
      inet addr:192.168.63.102  Bcast:192.168.63.255  Mask:255.255.255.0
      inet6 addr: fe80::3602:86ff:fe96:f398/64 Scope:Link
      UP BROADCAST RUNNING MULTICAST  MTU:1500  Metric:1
      RX packets:27733 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 frame:0
      TX packets:23098 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 carrier:0
      collisions:0 txqueuelen:1000 
      RX bytes:19054557 (19.0 MB)  TX bytes:4802812 (4.8 MB)
```

**cat /etc/resolv.conf**

```
# Dynamic resolv.conf(5) file for glibc resolver(3) generated by   resolvconf(8)
#     DO NOT EDIT THIS FILE BY HAND -- YOUR CHANGES WILL BE OVERWRITTEN
nameserver 127.0.1.1
search connectify
```

**cat /etc/network/interfaces**

```
auto lo
iface lo inet loopback
```

**lspci | grep Ethernet**

```
05:00.1 Ethernet controller: Realtek Semiconductor Co., Ltd.    RTL8111/8168/8411
PCI Express Gigabit Ethernet Controller (rev 12)
```

**Update:**

The answer below used to temporarily start my internet once in a while but didn't fix it permanently. So eventually after a couple of regular minor updates from Ubuntu my ethernet started working again. So I guess if the common solutions on the internet don't work and your ethernet stopped working just after an update you should probably wait for the next update.

Comment: Why does your ethernet have a 172.xx address while your wireless has 192.xx? Are they connected to the same router or...??

Comment: It is probably because the laptop is connected to the internet using connectify.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

open  `/etc/network/interfaces` using

```
sudo vi  /etc/network/interfaces
```

add line

```
auto eth0 
iface eth0 inet dhcp
```

then do

```
sudo ifdown eth0
sudo ifup eth0
```

you are saying `sudo dhclient eth0` working so do above change it will search for DHCP when you start system also make sure you have proper proxy setting in your system .current `ifconfig` output shows your system getting IP from DHCP.

**EDIT:** For  `device not managed` you have to open `/etc/NetworkManager/NetworkManager.conf` using command :

```
sudo vi /etc/NetworkManager/NetworkManager.conf
```

and change the line `managed=false` to `managed=true` and restart `NetworkManager`

```
sudo service network-manager restart
```

For more info related this problem you can take help from Askubuntu another question [network manager says “device not managed”](https://askubuntu.com/questions/71159/network-manager-says-device-not-managed)

Comment: So I did what you suggested. After rebooting my loading screen said something like " Waiting for network configuration" and after a minute it said " Booting without full network configuration" . After booting my network manager was stopped. So I started it using "sudo service network-manager start" and then it showed "device not managed" below my ethernet network.

Comment: If I remove the 2 lines you suggested from /etc/network/interfaces then the "device not managed" message disappears.

Comment: Here is a cropped snapshot of "device not managed" message.
[link](http://imgur.com/b6kL4b5)

Comment: @imhobo i have added to my answer please check

Comment: Hey thank you. Changing "managed=false" temporarily started my internet and also removed the "device not managed" message.  But it is still not working after reboot. I now have a new ethernet connection called "IfUpDown (eth0)" which doesn't connect whereas my orignal "Auto Ethernet" connects but doesn't run the internet.

Comment: Also I am not sure if I get my IP from DHCP. I have an IP address assigned by my institute which I have to use to connect to the internet.  It is manually configured in my "Auto Ethernet" connection.

Comment: I also tried changing "iface eth0 inet dhcp " to "iface eth0 inet static"

Comment: if you use `iface eth0 inet static` then you have to add static ip , netmask , gatway etc. like http://askubuntu.com/questions/338442/how-to-set-static-ip-address  if you know ip otherwise try again by removing `auto eth0  iface eth0 inet dhcp `  from  /etc/network/interfaces and restart system. your dhcp will work without this . always before starting to your system add LAN wire to system and then start system .it will take less time to take ip faster and at starting if you add wire after that then you have to wait for some time it will work. i think you meshed up settings.

Answer (score 0):

Ethernet fix after Ubuntu update:

1. Execute the below command in terminal:

   ```
   sudo -H gedit /etc/network/interfaces
   ```
2. Add  the below two lines ( the primary network interface) and save:

   ```
   auto eth0

   iface eth0 inet dhcp
   ```
3. Execute the below command in terminal:

   ```
   sudo nano /etc/udev/rules.d/70-persistent-net.rules
   ```
4. The above command will open editor inside terminal, you will find the below lines present (if not please add these):

   `ATTR{address}` is your adapter mac address and `NAME="eth0"`

   ```
   SUBSYSTEM=="net", ACTION=="add", DRIVERS=="?*", ATTR{address}=="0a:03:27:c2:b4:eb", ATTR{type}=="1", KERNEL=="eth*", NAME="eth0"
   ```
5. Save and reboot.