# Refused connection to SSH

Tags: ssh

I've tried to access the Ubuntu platform using SSH, SCP, and SFTP and got refused with a message. I tried `service ssh restart` and got:

> ssh:unrecognized service

I also typed `sudo ufw disable` in order to disable the firewall, but it still did not let me in. How can I fix this?

Comment: Have you installed `openssh` ?

Comment: Check list of SSH packages by running `dpkg-query -W | grep ssh` in Terminal. Default installation should have `openssh-client`. But, you will need `openssh-server` also.

Answer (score 3):

Chances are you don't have ssh server installed. Use this to install it:

```
sudo apt-get install openssh-server
```

To check if it is running:

```
sudo service ssh status
```

Try that and see if you can connect to it.

Comment: Thanks it works .
I run `sudo dhclient eth0` (-: 
my computer has static IP therefore all my trials to install the openssh-server fails .

Comment: Glad to hear you got it to work. If you have issues setting up a static IP, take a look here: http://askubuntu.com/questions/338442/how-to-set-static-ip-address

Answer (score 2):

You have to install `openssh` in order to use the SSH protocol.

On the machine you want to access, install it by running :

```
sudo apt-get install openssh-server
```

Instead of disabling your firewall, allow port 22 :

```
sudo ufw allow 22
```