# Unable to ping box after logout

Tags: networking, server, 16.04

I have a physical machine running ubuntu server 16.04, and I am having a bit of trouble interacting with it. When I run `ifconfig` I see it's public IP address, but when I try to ping it from another machine nothing happens.

What I have been able to do in order to interact with it, is on the server, login as some user, run `sudo service networking restart` and then I can interact with the machine remotely (ping for example). However, the second I run `exit` or `logout` on the server, I can no longer interact with it again.

It's also worth noting that I don't seem to be able to ping anything from the server until I restart the networking like I mentioned just above. Once I restart networking, I can ping out, but again once I log out and in again, I am back where I started.

How can I begin to have the networking setup such that it simply works on boot?

The contents of `/etc/network/interfaces` is:

```
# This file describes the network interfaces available on your system
# and how to activate them. For more information, see interfaces(5).

source /etc/network/interfaces.d/*

# The loopback network interface
auto lo
iface lo inet loopback

# The primary network interface
auto enp8s0
iface enp8s0 inet dhcp
```

UPDATE:

It would appear that even after restarting the networking service, I can still only intermittently ping it.

Comment: Please provide the contents of /etc/networking/interfaces

Comment: I have updated the original post with the contents of that file

Comment: How are you able to ping the machine if it has a dynamic IP address? Is this running a desktop environment and, by default, Network Manager?

Comment: It looks like you're using an SFP based network card. Is this correct? When you log off, are the lights still lit? Who is the device maker?

Comment: @chili555 the machine has no desktop environment, just the command line available to me.

Comment: @JaredStarkey It is an onboard ethernet controller. `lshw` tells me the card is a `RTL8111/8168/8411 PCI Express Gigabit Ethernet Controller`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I suggest the following `/etc/network/interfaces` file:

```
auto lo
iface lo inet loopback

auto enp8s0
iface enp8s0 inet static
address 192.168.254.120 
netmask 255.255.255.0
gateway 192.168.254.1
dns-nameservers 8.8.8.8 192.168.254.1
```

Be sure to select an address outside the range used for DHCP in the router. Of course, substitute your details here.

Now get the system to read and use the changes:

```
sudo ifdown enp8s0 && sudo ifup enp8s0
```

Check that you can reach the internet:

```
ping -c3 www.ubuntu.com
```

Comment: This wound up doing the trick for me! I had to do some editing as my machine has a public IP address, but this was definitely the right path.

Answer (score 0):

Please use [the method from the second answer](https://askubuntu.com/questions/338442/how-to-set-static-ip-address) to edit your interfaces file and set a static IP.

Comment: If you need help calculating some of the network addresses, please give us your networking information.

Comment: This should probably be a comment.  IMHO

Answer (score -1):

You can try `/etc/rc.local`. To run a command at startup, use
`sudo nano /etc/rc.local` and at the first availble line, type `sudo networking restart`. hope this helps

Comment: This kind of solution is a little scary, personally speaking. Its a workaround that ignores whatever the core issue is. Who knows though, it may solve the problem.

Comment: rc.local is only invoked at boot, not logout/in. Moreover, restarting networking is deprecated.