# Need example netplan yaml for static ip

Tags: networking

I want to migrate my network configuration to netplan. I have been using ifup/down and the /etc/network/interfaces file to configure my static IPs, but this has been deprecated and support will be withdrawn in the 17.10 release.

However

```
sudo netplan ifupdown-migrate
```

returns

```
enp0s3: method static is not supported
```

So how do I convert this `/etc/network/interfaces` stanza?

```
auto enp0s3
  iface enp0s3 inet static
  address 192.168.0.123
  netmask 255.255.255.0
  gateway 192.168.0.1
  dns-nameservers 8.8.8.8  8.8.4.4
```

- What does the complete file look like?
- How should it be named and placed?

Thank you.

Comment: Welcome to Ask Ubuntu. This is a question and answer site, so rather than adding 'solved' and putting the solution in the question, please put the solution in the answer space. After a short period of time, you will be able to accept the solution as the correct answer.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

After looking through the man page I came up with this:

```
  network:
    version: 2
    ethernets:
      enp0s3:
        addresses: [192.168.0.140/24]
        gateway4: 192.168.0.1
        nameservers:
          addresses: [8.8.8.8,8.8.4.4]
```

It is named

```
/etc/netplan/01-systemd-networkd-eth.yaml
```

And it works.

This command was a great help:

```
netplan --debug generate
```

which pointed me to syntactical errors.

Breaking news. Just found this:
https://insights.ubuntu.com/2017/07/05/quick-and-easy-network-configuration-with-netplan/

Comment: A more recent man page now that Ubuntu Artful has been released: http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/artful/man5/netplan.5.html