# What happened to the eth0 file?

Tags: networking

There is so much information out there on Ubuntu, I’m not sure where to look.  I’ve been using some images for my odroid SBC, and older images used to have a file **/etc/network/interfaces.d/eth0** where I would set a static ip address.  On newer images, that file is gone, and in fact there are no files in that directory at all.

Did something fundamental happen to the way interfaces are now configured?

Comment: /etc/dhcpcd.conf but I'm not sure if Ubuntu works this way, I know this is what I have to do on Raspbian...only lurking here for more knowledge.

Answer (score 1):

The NIC configuration is now located in /etc/netplan/01-netcfg.yaml

[Need example netplan yaml for static ip](https://askubuntu.com/questions/961552/need-example-netplan-yaml-for-static-ip/961759)

https://websiteforstudents.com/configuring-static-ips-ubuntu-17-10-servers/

Comment: Is netplan used for all Ubuntu versions or just recent ones? What version does the OP have?