# Ubuntu server 19.04 internet connection problem

Tags: networking, server, internet, 19.04

I have already installed Ubuntu server. I plugged in ethernet cabel and i have not got internet connection. After run ifconfig result is:

```
lo: flags=73<IP,LOOPBACK,RUNNING> mtu 65536
inet 127.0.0.1 netmask 255.0.0.0
inet6 ::1 prefixlen 128 scopeid 0x10<host>
loop txqueuelen 1000 (Local Loopback)
RX packets 128 bytes 9440 (9.4KB)
RX errors 0 dropped 0 overruns 0 frame 0
TX packets 128 bytes 9440 (9.4KB)
TX errors 0 dropped 0 overruns 0 carrier 0 collisions 0
```

And result of lspci -knn | grep Eth -A3:

```
3:00.0 Ethernet controller [0200]: Realtek Semiconductor Co., Ltd. RTL8111/8168/8411 PCI Express Gigabit Ethernet Controller  [10ec:8168] (rev 06)
Subsystem: ASUStek Computer Inc. P8P67 and other motherboards [1043:8432]
Kernel driver in use: r8169
Kernel modules: r8169
-
6:01.0 Ethernet controller [0200]: Realtek Semiconductor Co., Ltd. RTL-8100/8101L/8139 PCI Fast Ethernet Adapter [10ec:8139] (rev10)
Subsystem: Realtek Semiconductor Co., Ltd. RTL-8100/8101L/8139 PCI Fast Ethernet Adapter [10ec:8139]
Kernel driver in use: 8139too
Kernel modules: 8139cp, 8139too
f:00.0 Host bridge [0600]: Intel Corporation Core Processor QuickPath Architecture Generic Non-core Registers [8086:2c61] (rev 05)
```

I read about editing `/etc/network/interface` but i haven't got file something like that in my system.

I was looking for a solution of my problem but I found nothing working for me. Anyone have idea how to turn on this internet connection?

Answer (score 0):

Using the netplan command is the new way to configure networking in more recent versions of Ubuntu. Please try setting your IP settings manually with it and see if the issue persists.

https://www.linux.com/tutorials/how-use-netplan-network-configuration-tool-linux/
You can find the explanation within this source. If using netplan try results in a error, try to run `netplan --debug generate`

It is pretty precise with its indentations, so don't use tabs and only use spaces to markup the netplan.

Here is another StackExchange topic about its configuration:

[Need example netplan yaml for static ip](https://askubuntu.com/questions/961552/need-example-netplan-yaml-for-static-ip)