# Why isn't the interface shown in the Virtual Network Editor?

Tags: server, vmware, ip, interface

I am pretty new to Ubuntu so I tried to change my static IP address, and sometimes it works and the IP address changes.

I shutdown the OS, and my static IP address changes, but I can ping to others. When I check virtual network editor, my interface didn't show up.

There is no `eth0` in virtual network editor:

[image]

Comment: The `eth0` interface is shown as `VMnet8`. It's almost definitely not set up as a static IP address. It probably uses DHCP to get an address.

Comment: You have to check in the properties of the VM what NIC is connected to which virtual network. Please note that the default for host only is DHCP.

Comment: how to change it to static?

Comment: Run the following command, copy the output, paste it into your question, select the text, and press the `{}` button in the editor. If you are on Ubuntu 14.04, run `nmcli dev list iface eth0`. Otherwise, run `nmcli device show eth0`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `eth0` interface is shown as `VMnet8`. To set up a static IP address on NAT, [VMware Workstation's documentation says that you must use an address ending somewhere in `3` to `127`](https://www.vmware.com/support/ws5/doc/ws_net_advanced_ipaddress.html).

To change the address to static, you can follow the instructions on [an answer to a question about setting up static IP addresses on Ubuntu](https://askubuntu.com/a/338854/616451) (which I've modified below to better suit you):

> Edit `/etc/network/interfaces` to reflect something like this:
>
> ```
> # This file describes the network interfaces available on your system
> # and how to activate them. For more information, see interfaces(5).
> # The loopback network interface
> auto lo
> iface lo inet loopback
>
> # The primary network interface
> auto eth0
> iface eth0 inet static
> address 192.168.59.3
> netmask 255.255.255.0
> network 192.168.0.0
> broadcast 192.168.0.255
> gateway 192.168.59.2
> dns-nameservers 192.168.59.2
> ```
>
> Then do a:
>
> ```
> sudo /etc/init.d/networking restart
> ```

Change `192.168.59.3` to other addresses up to `192.168.59.127` for other virtual machines that need a static IP address.