# Edit network connections with tightVNCserver

Tags: ubuntu-mate, vncviewer, tightvncserver

For an embedded device I have an raspberry pi which is hard to reach. I need to change the IP but it's running ubuntumate and the networkmanager keeps acting like a #*%K. I installed a tightvncserver on the pi so I could edit the connections through remote desktop, but now i can't edit the network connections through it.

[image: Screenshot]

Any idea how to solve this? Any help is welcome

Comment: IIRC policykit (`pklocalauthority`) does not allow remote users to modify network settings - but unless you're familiar with how to edit policykit files, you may find it easier to address the original issue (what exactly does *"networkmanager keeps acting like a #*%K"* mean?)

Comment: That I tryd [https://askubuntu.com/questions/110735/how-do-i-set-a-static-ip-address] this method and a lot of others but it still aint working