# How do I assign a static IP address in Ubuntu 17.04 without rebooting?

Tags: networking, dhcp, ip, ifconfig

How do I assign static IP addresses to interfaces in Ubuntu (17.04)
without rebooting the machine?  This is pretty straightforward on a
Unix machine, but I'm having trouble on this one.

Please don't mark this as duplicate (just yet).  I've read a number of
other posts, but the instructions don't seem to work.

I'm configuring a bunch of routers and switches and I need to be able to:

- Permanently (survives a reboot/crash) change the the IP of an interface
- Permanently (survives a reboot/crash) change the interface back to DHCP (or BOOTP, or whatever)
- Make these changes without X (and with, from an `xterm`).

I've already tried editing `/etc/network/interfaces` and running `/etc/init.d/networking restart` as mentioned [here](https://askubuntu.com/questions/110735/how-do-i-set-a-static-ip-address).  This failed to change anything until I rebooted.

The machine was originally set up with DHCP.  I'd like to be able to go back and forth quickly.  The machine has several interfaces, and because it's used to configure other people's networks, I need to be able to switch them with as little fuss as possible.

If I boot it with a static IP, what do I need to do the get a DHCP address?

If I boot with DHCP and switch to static, will I have to kill off `dhclient`?  What about other DHCP controlled interfaces?

Thanks.
-E

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Network manager is service manager networking on your Linux , This service contain some interfaces to work with it . **nmcli** is one of the richest interface to manager networking .

If you want set static IP to your Linux via *nmcli* try following command :

```
$ nmcli connection modify eth0 ipv4.address x.x.x.x/y
```

With above command you permanently add IP to your interface . ( replace eth0 with your interface name ) .

Than run following comand :

```
$ nmcli connection up eth0
```

To active your connection without rebooting .

Comment: Cool beans.  Thanks @Ali.  So what is `/etc/network/interfaces` for?  And what happens if it conflicts with, for example, `/etc/NetworkManager/system-connections/ethernet-ens1`?  I don't know how to get a newline in the comment, but here is what I did: `nmcli connection add  type ethernet ifname ens1 ; nmcli connection edit ethernet-ens1 ; nmcli -p con up ifname ens1`

Comment: Also, I notice the `nmcli` differs between Ubuntu versions.  I only mention it for future explorers. -E

Comment: Well  all NIC have configuration file which you can find under *etc* but it's not recommended to edit them by hand . In most case you need to rebooting machine to be cared of by newtork manager . That why we use command like `nmcli` and `nmtui` .

Comment: To add up you should set a connection profile in new network manager . Every NIC can have a different profile but only one profile can be active on the time .

Comment: Good pointers.  I didn't know about the different profiles.

Answer (score 0):

I found `NetworkManager` to be too unpredictable for my use.  The answers, in my case were to be found in the [interfaces(5)](http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/zesty/en/man5/interfaces.5.html) man page.  More discussion on `NetworkManager` may be found [here](http://xmodulo.com/disable-network-manager-linux.html).  This is not an indictment of NetworkManager, but rather a note that it didn't work for me.  Everytime I would unplug the interface from the switch and move it to a different port, NetworkManager would go to work reconfiguring the interface on my machine.